# CLLocationManager didUpdateToLocation, bring values to a NSString to use elsewhere!

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, cllocationmanager

Using NSLog(@"%@",longi) outside this function crashes my application.... How can I use this NSLog outside the didUpdateToLocation function? Like in a IBAction function.

This example works great! But How to use this NSLogs outside this one?

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {


    longi = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%g", newLocation.coordinate.longitude];
    lati = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%g", newLocation.coordinate.latitude];


    NSLog(@"%@",longi);
    NSLog(@"%@",lati);



}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store this values in NSUserDefaults and access them whenever needed.

Comment: K great, but it's actually something it doesn't need to remember next time, everything happens in the same view controller and when done all this values are useless.

Comment: Then use a class variable...and initialize it to some default value.In this function you update the value.